# Calculating Resistance

Tags: resistance

Can somebody tell me why R_o2 is RD
Why dont we take Rs into consideration ?

Their answer is Ro2=vt/it = Rd

My question is why didnt they take in consideration Rs and the current source?

[image]

Comment: Please be specific !

Comment: @LongPham Updated. Cant be more specific than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your diagram, we can see a voltage controlled current source.

The control voltage is \$V_{GS}\$. And \$V_{GS}\cdot g_m\$ current can only flow if \$V_{GS}\$ voltage is larger or smaller than \$0V\$. But in your circuit \$V_{GS} = 0V\$ therfore \$V_{GS}\cdot g_m\$ also must be zero.

The situation will be different if you add \$r_o\$ resistor between the drain and the source terminal. In this case \$V_{GS}\$ is no longer equal to \$0V\$. Because now \$r_o\$ provides a path for a current from \$V_t\$ to GND. So the voltage at \$V_S\$ is larger than \$0V\$

[I/O Resistance of common source MOSFET with source degeneration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966)

Comment: Wait, how did you get that Vgs = 0? I know that `Vg = 0`. But why `Vs=0` ?

Comment: @SijaanHallak To turn-on VCCS you need Vgs voltage to appears first. Is this possible in your circuit?

Comment: Doesnt Rs get some voltage from our test voltage? @g35

Comment: @SijaanHallak How?

Comment: Vt is in parallel with the VCCS and Rs, so some of the voltage will drop on Rs ... correct me if I'm wrong which I feel I am

Comment: Do you agree with this Vs = Id*Rs and to Id current to flow you need Vgs first right?

Comment: I get it now! Saved me a lot of time. Thanks. Would be appreciated if you can give me some more questions and answers of yours about CS.

Comment: Which questions?

Answer (score 2):

R_o2 is the impedance looking into the drain node from the perspective of \$V_t\$. That drain has two other connections: -

1. A current source that has infinite impedance (irrespective of what is connected to the source) i.e. it is the actual drain connection and,
2. Resistor \$R_D\$

Hence the signal impedance R_o2 is \$R_D\$.