# Output Resistance - Small-Signal MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am doing a question (I have broken the problem down to this sub-problem) which requires me to find the output resistance below:

[image]

I tried to do the small-signal analysis to find it by adding an extra voltage source and finding Vx and Ix. However, I'm stuck now. I can solve the problem if just ro2 was there, but the ro3 to GND is making it difficult to find the current Ix.

[image]

Comment: To determine a resistance or an impedance, you have to stimulate the circuit with a current source \$I_T\$ while the response \$V_T\$ appears across its terminals. In your case, once the current source is installed instead of your voltage source, express the \$I_T\$ current versus the other elements and \$V_T\$. Then factor the whole thing to have \$\frac{V_T}{I_T}=...\$ and this is the resistance you want. A quick SPICE simulation showing operating points with \$I_T\$ set to 1 A will confirm your results - or not : )

Comment: Take a look at this example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966

Answer (score 0):

Vgs(th) =Vt has a wide Mfg. and temperature tolerance    50%? Measured at some arbitrary low std current threshold.

- yet **1-Vgs/Vt= k** controls both Ron or **RdsOn =1/gm**.
- source output impedance = **Ron +Rd =Rout** here
- RdsOn is usually rated around k = 2.5 to 5. Or both where the difference is small.
- thus for Vt = 2 to 4V , Ron might be rated at 10V ( these are all the old enh FETs )
- newer Fets with lower Vt were designed for “Logic level” thus rated at 3V or 5V for Vgs and Ron
- there is also a strong temperature shift included in this tolerance of Vt.

.

- So you get the idea , that computing it is not so easy but you expect Ron to be <= Rd in a linear design and < 2% of Rd for an efficient switch.
- Yet I have given you **hints** to solve Rout
- but if you make Ron << Rd then you must be aware that Coss * Ron is somewhat constant in a given design so that can affect turn off time.
- So choose your FET Ron wisely, otherwise you need your thermodynamic skills to design the heatsink