# is this small signal equivalent circuit of mosfet amplifier correct?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, small-signal

We are given an assigment about mosfet common source amplifiers and we are given this circuit. I drew its small signal equivalent circuit but I am so unsure about placement of ro(transistor resistor). Can you tell me if it is correct or not and help me if it is not correct

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct small signal model of a common source MOSFET amplifier. You’ve placed Ro correctly across drain and source terminals. 
Also your input impedance would simply be R1||R2 while your output impedance is RD||(1+ gmRs)Ro. This is a little more complex to derive but can be done with circuit analysis.

See this link for Analysis:
[I/O Resistance of common source MOSFET with source degeneration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration)

Note: I used Microelectronic circuits 6th sedra/Smith so they approximate output resistance as RD||(1+ gmRs)Ro.

Comment: should not output impedance be seen after RD(right to drain word in circuit)? I am asking to make sure because I also need to derive it. Thanks a lot and can you give some tips to calculate it using node analysis etc.

Comment: I edited the post. I forgot to include RS. Also gave a link to someone who analyzed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

your circuit is correct. r0 is also placed correctly.

Comment: thank you first of all. if it is not too much, can you tell me how to find input resistance? I look it up in my book but it did not explain it. I believe input resistance is taken from node G in the circuit below(small signal equivalent circuit)

Comment: @EEstudent Rin = Vg/Ig in your circuit we have Ig= Vg/(R1|R2) thus Rin = R1||R2