# output impedance confusion

Tags: bjt

[image]

Here is a typical diagram of a bjt amplifier. so whenever we talk about output impedance (unloaded)do we mean the impedance (AC) between the point V_0 and ground? and also we say "loaded impedance" that just means we have now just added the load R_L;  in this case what are those two point we are considering between we are suppose to measure the impedance? how about the term "loaded output impedance"? which is R_C||R_L, this impedance appears between the point X and ground. seems like now we are considering the point X and ground as our output port, which is not. so what does it mean to have a loaded output impedance? and where to measure it?

Comment: The output impedance is an "AC resistance" see from the load resistance point of view.  It is a Thevenin resistance seen by RL resistance. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we consider the output impedance of an amplifier we assume that the amplifier's supply voltage is ideal i.e. it presents itself as an impedance of zero ohm. A battery is a reasonable example; it might have an output impedance of 1 Ω or less and, in terms of the type of amplifier shown in your picture, that might as well be considered to be 0 Ω. Bear this in mind.

> *so whenever we talk about output impedance (unloaded)do we mean the
> impedance (AC) between the point V_0 and ground?*

If we are talking about the unloaded amplifier then we ignore \$R_L\$ and assume it is infinite and, because we are happy to assume that the supply to the amplifier has got zero Ω source impedance, the amplifier will have the same output impedance from \$v_0\$ to either supply rail.

This is why we say that the unloaded output impedance is purely \$R_C\$ (ignoring any extra impedance produced by \$C_{C2}\$).

> *how about the term "loaded output impedance"?*

We hardly ever care about this because, if the output is loaded then anything to understand about the effect of loading is already covered by examining the unloaded output impedance.

> *so what does it mean to have a loaded output impedance?*

It doesn't really mean much unless we are considering how much current the BJT is having to pass to create such and such a voltage output.

> *seems like now we are considering the point X and ground as our output
> port*

We can consider point X as having the same output impedance to ground as node \$v_0\$ only if we assume that the reactance of the capacitor (\$C_{C2}\$) is close to zero AND, in many circumstances it is.