# Equivalent impedance through a transistor

Tags: transistors, impedance

I'm looking for the equation of the equivalent impedance through the network. This is all the information I was given, other than that the transistor is biased in the saturation region and rds isn't infinity. I guess I'm confused, after changing the transistor to a t model can't you just go through the drain into the voltage source and have no impedance?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode

Comment: Try to read through this example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966

Comment: Step one is to draw the **small signal equivalent model**, did you do that?

Comment: I think I redrew it as the small signal eq, I have the transistor replaced with a dependent current source at the drain side and a resistor on the source side. but from there wouldn't the path of least resistance just go through the dependent current source and voltage source then down to ground, avoiding all the resistors?