# Output resistance of Cs stage with source degeneration (MOSFET)

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

In Razabi's Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits textbook, when he calculates the output resistance of a common source stage with source degeneration,

[image]

He uses the small-signal model below:

[image]

My question is, why doesn't he include R_D in his small-signal model?

Comment: Maybe you have misread what was said in the book.

Comment: He says, "Another important consequence of source degeneration is the increase in the output resistance of the stage." Then he starts calculating Rout. So is he just interested in the bottom half of the circuit?

Comment: That is a logical conclusion

Comment: Proper context, and extracts as images yes. Possible misquotes or paraphrasing no.

Comment: Here you can find the answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't include $R_D$ to simplify the signal model. As $R_D$ is shunt at the output, you can add it on after you calculate the above $R_o$. The total output impedance will be $R_o || R_D$.