# Thevenins equivalent resistance with only dependent sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, small-signal

What is the Rth of the below circuit Given R=R1=R2=10 ohms and g=10 siemens.

Below is my solution.I am getting a value of 0.2 Ohms for Rth.May I know is this correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to show us your calculations first.

Comment: Trying test source method but not getting the answer

Comment: This is the proper method, simply show your work. So that we can see where you made the mistake.

Comment: Take a a look at this example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966

Comment: @newbie How is it that a non-zero current may occur in **R**?

Comment: @G36,Added my solution.I am getting a value of 0.2 Ohms for Rth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job your answer is correct.

Notice that only one equation is needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTXBko.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$V_X = \left( I_X+ (g_m (-V_X) \right )R_2 + I_X R_1 $$

$$V_X = \left( I_X - V_X \:g_m \right )R_2 + I_X R_1 $$
$$V_X = I_X R_2 - V_X \:g_m \:R_2 + I_X R_1 $$
$$V_X + V_X \:g_m R_2 = I_X R_2 + I_X R_1 $$
$$V_X(1 + \:g_m R_2) = I_X(R_2 + R_1)$$
$$V_X = I_X \frac{R_2 + R_1}{1 + \:g_m R_2}$$

And finally
$$R_{TH} = \frac{V_X}{I_X} = \frac{R_2 + R_1}{1 + \:g_m R_2} = \frac{10\Omega + 10\Omega}{1 + 10S \: 10\Omega} = \frac{20}{101} [\Omega] \approx 0.2 \Omega$$