# Small signal model

Tags: current, source

I would want to derive the output impedance of the following current source stage. I tried to convert it in small signal, could you please tell me if I'm wrong and how I can derive it to have output impedance?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWmMIg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your small signal looks good to me. But I redrawn it to this form:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZvtP3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the output resistance will be equal to \$R_{OUT} = \frac{V_X}{I_X}\$

Take a look at the example of how to do it:

[I/O Resistance of common source MOSFET with source degeneration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966)

And supper simplified version of \$R_{OUT}\$ equation will look like this

\$ \large R_{OUT} \approx r_{o1}+ r_{o1}\beta \approx r_{o1}\beta\$

Comment: thanks a lot it's more clear with your schematic